# Edit Action column is not showing in admin grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, grid-layout, action

[image]

Why the edit option is not displaying in the action column. Kindly help me. 
My Action.php code:

```
<?php

namespace AdminGrid\Grid\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Action extends Column
{
    /** Url path */
    const ROW_EDIT_URL = 'grid/grid/addrow';
    /** @var UrlInterface */
    protected $_urlBuilder;


    private $_editUrl;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        $editUrl = self::ROW_EDIT_URL
    ) 
    {
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->_editUrl = $editUrl;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }


    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {
                    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                        'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            $this->_editUrl, 
                            ['id' => $item['entity_id']]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Edit'),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">grid_records_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Row</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="grid_record_grid_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">​_
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/massdelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">grid_record_grid_list.grid_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="grid_records_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                   <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </selectionsColumn>
       <column name="title">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="image" class="AdminGrid\Grid\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Thumbnail">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                  <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                  <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                  <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                  <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="text1" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Text 1</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="text2" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Text 2</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="link" > 
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Link</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="publish_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Publish Date</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>

       <!-- Add Action with each row of grid and for this we will create a class Action -->
       <actionsColumn name="actions" class="AdminGrid\Grid\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

[image]

I am getting some js errors.

Comment: add your xml too

Comment: Added. Please see and tell me.

Comment: add your full xml

Comment: Added. Will you check now?

Comment: Your error is on XML code, particularly in filters section. I was getting same error, but in my case, I don't needed filters in my grid.
I hope to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please replace this node. I change from `id` to `entity_id`.

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="AdminGrid\Grid\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It working now.

Comment: But it sometimes disappearing. Why??

Comment: I don't know, sorry .

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam If I helped, please select my answer as the best

Comment: this is my exact problem. Can you answer this? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281971/issue-with-edit-option-in-action-column-admin-grid

Comment: Sure,  only  please select my answer as the best  here

Comment: Done. Kindly answer to that problem.

Comment: Now let's see what you have there

Comment: I updated that xml code here itself. Can you check it again? It actually works but simply it often not displaying edit hyperlink in the action column, it looks empty.

Comment: you say that it works, but often disappears? For such an error you need to work with the code, look at the console, maybe there are javascript errors

Comment: Yeah I checked now itself. There are some js errors. Please see the screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace id to entity_id.

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="AdminGrid\Grid\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as $itKey => $item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {
                    $dataSource['data']['items'][$itKey][$name]['edit'] = [
                        'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            $this->_editUrl, 
                            ['id' => $item['entity_id']]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Edit'),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: This is so weird. @saravanavelu why did you [approve this edit?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/188797)

Comment: Cc ^ @Jai, what's the rationale for approving this destructive edit?

Answer (score 0):

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Mastering\SampleModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ItemActions" sortOrder="200">
                    <settings>
                        <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
                    </settings>

        </actionsColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was an issue with the key['value'] in the Ui Component actions file, as my table primary key was `entity_id` not `id`

Actual Result format was : `$item['id']`
Required format was : `$item['entity_id']`

Below is my working example code :

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'edit' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_EDIT_PATH,
                                [
                                    'entity_id' => $item['entity_id'
                                    ],
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit'),
                        ],
                        'delete' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_DELETE_PATH,
                                [
                                    'entity_id' => $item['entity_id'
                                    ],
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Delete'),
                        ],
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="[Vender]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
               <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
               <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </actionsColumn>
```