# Why the edit hyperlink in action column is not displaying often in custom admin grid?

Tags: magento2, module, grid

[image]

That edit option in action column is working fine but it is not showing often. Please help me.

Action column code:

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="AdminGrid\Grid\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
               <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
               <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </actionsColumn>
```

Comment: show your action column code

Comment: Added. Please check it. I think it caused by js errors. Check my this question -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285645/edit-action-column-is-not-showing-in-admin-grid-in-magento-2